# Fork() and Wait() with execvp() in C

Tags: c, linux, fork, wait, execvp

I'm am trying to use the fork method to call a different program and wait until it completes,
I tried to check what is the problem and it seems that the wait function doesn't wait to the childReturns and it makes doesn't print the answer.
(the assignment was to loop compare method until ctrl+c )

the program I call is a comparator that compares 2  strings.

the problem is that the wait func doesn't wait for the child
the compile is GCC

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define LINELEN (80)

char *mygets(char *buf, int len);
char *progName(char *prog);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *args[3];
    char str1[LINELEN + 1];
    char str2[LINELEN + 1];
    int childReturns;
    if (argc != 2)
        return -1;

    char *prog = progName(argv[1]);
    if (prog == NULL)
        return -1;
    args[0] = prog;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter string:");
        if (mygets(str1, LINELEN) == NULL)
            break;
        printf("Enter  string:");
        if (mygets(str2, LINELEN) == NULL)
            break;
        args[1] = str1;
        args[2] = str2;
        int processId = fork();
        if (processId == 0)
            execvp(prog, args);
        else
        {
            wait(&childReturns); // Wait for the child
            printf("Child  code is %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(childReturns));
        }
    }
    free(prog);
    return 0;
}
char *progName(char *prog)
{
    char *filePath = (char *)malloc(strlen(prog) + 3);
    if (!filePath)
        return NULL;
    strcpy(filePath, "./");
    strcat(filePath, prog);
    return filePath;
}

char *mygets(char *buf, int len)
{
    char *retval;

    retval = fgets(buf, len, stdin);
    buf[len] = '\0';
    if (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == 10) /* trim \r */
        buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
    else if (retval)
        while (getchar() != '\n')
            ; /* get to eol */

    return retval;
} ```
````

Comment: The `args` array must be terminated with a null pointer.  You are using all three elements of `char *args[3];` for non-null strings.  Your call to `execvp()` is malformed.  Use `char *args[4] = { 0 };` or something equivalent to include a null pointer in the array passed to `execvp()`.  You also need a compound statement around the `execvp()` which exits after writing an error message if `execvp()` returns.  If `execvp()` is successful, it doesn't return; if it returns, it failed (no need to test the return value).  Without that exit, you end up with another process reading from your terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jonathan Leffler said the problem was with the args, `execvp()` needs that the array off args has in the end `NULL`.

and that fixed the problem.

the Right code :

````
    char str1[LINELEN + 1];
    char str2[LINELEN + 1];
    int childReturns = 1;
    if (argc != 2)
        return -1;

    char *prog = progName(argv[1]);
    if (prog == NULL)
        return -1;
    char *args[4];
    args[3] = NULL;
    args[0] = prog;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter string:");
        if (mygets(str1, LINELEN) == NULL)
            break;
        printf("Enter  string:");
        if (mygets(str2, LINELEN) == NULL)
            break;
        args[1] = str1;
        args[2] = str2;
        int processId = fork();
        if (processId == 0)
        {
            execvp(prog, args);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(&childReturns); // Wait for the child
            printf("Child  code is %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(childReturns));
        }
    }
    free(prog);
    return 0;```
````

Comment: Still missing the `if (execvp(prog, args) == -1) { perror("execvp-failed"); _exit(1); }` Use of `_exit()` is preferred over `exit()` after `exec...` because it does not run any functions set by `atexit()` or `on_exit()` which are invalidated by the `execvp` failure.

Answer (score 1):

Try chaining these lines:

```
        if (processId == 0)
            execvp(prog, args);
        else
```

To these:

```
        if (processId == 0) {
            execvp(prog, args);
            perror(prog);
            abort();
        } else
```

Also, note that WEXITSTATUS, is only valid if WIFEXITTED() is true.   In this case, when your child process abort()'s, it will not be true.
So

```
            wait(&childReturns); // Wait for the child
            printf("Child  code is %d\n",
```

needs a bit more work, like:

```
     if (WIFEXITTED(childReturns)) {
         printf("Child code is %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(childReturns));
     } else if (WIFSIGNALED(childReturns)) {
         printf("Child killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(childReturns);
     } else {
         printf("Child suffered %#x\n", childReturns);
     }
```

But, your real problem is why is execvp() failing?   Look carefully at how big your *args* array is. Does it match the documentation?

Comment: So how can I print in the Parent process (the else section) the result from the execvp ?

Answer (score 0):

`fork()` system call duplicates the mother process. The resulting child process and the parent process will have their own address spaces. So child process can not modify `childReturns` variable of the parent.

Additionally, `wait(NULL)` waits for child processes to end.